# How to get object's method from child component with destructuring it in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-props, destructuring

This is the object I want to pass to the child, and I want to pass getFullName function too, how can I do it, the error message says ReferenceError: firstName is not defined
at getFullName (:15:22)

```
const person = {
     id: 1,
     firstName: "John",
     lastName: "Smith",
     getFullName: function() { 
          return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
     }
}
```

This is the child component

```
const Person = (props) => {
    const { id, firstName, lastName, getFullName } = props.person

    return (
        <>
            <div>{ id }</div>
            <div>{ firstName } { lastName }</div>
            <div>{ getFullName() }</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

It says that getFullName is not found

Comment: Please add some explanation of the code you've included. What are you trying to accomplish, and what is going wrong with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

> ReferenceError: firstName is not defined at getFullName (:15:22)

That's because `getFullName` is looking for variables named `firstName` and `lastName`, which don't exist. What you have instead are properties of the object `person` named `firstName` and `lastName`. The return value of `getFullName` should be referencing those as properties of the parent object,

```
     getFullName: function() { 
          return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
     }
```

> It says that getFullName is not found

We would have to see the parent component to diagnose this issue. The child component should be invoked something like this:

```
<Child person={person} />
```

and if person is properly defined, your child component as written should work fine.

Comment: small correction we need to do  on child component,  here is the full code https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hill-1x1s4v?file=/src/Person.tsx